# how to convert yolov7.pt to .weights. so i can use it for object detection and training

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, onnx, darknet

below is the code where i need to use the yolov7.weights file.

```
import os, time
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coco_classes = ['person', 'bicycle', ...]


net = cv2.dnn.readNet("weight","cfg")
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1 / 255, swapRB=True)

path = './testimg/'

for fn in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path + fn)

 
    c, v, b = model.detect(image, 0.2, 0.4)
 

    c = [coco_classes[x] for x in c]

    for (classid, score, box) in zip(c, v, b):
        if classid == 0 or classid == 2:
            lx, ly, cw, ch = box
        x=cv2.rectangle(image, box, (255, 0, 255), 3)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

currently i have only .pt files. i have tried to use .onnx conversion and it got converted but i am not able to use it in the below code as i am getting some cv2 error -

```
error: (-5:Bad argument) Can't read ONNX file: models/yolov7_640x640.onnx in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'
```

. so i am now interested to convert it into .weights

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: 1) error says, it's still [a 404 problem](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp#L257) 2) there's no conversion onnx -> weights 3) keep an eye on https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22290